# Gaussian integral in C++ is not working. Why?

Tags: c++, int, double, precision

Here is my code:

```
const double kEps(0.00000001);
    double gaussianIntegral(double x)
    {
        double res(x), numerator(x);
        for(unsigned int i(1), k(3); (abs(numerator/k) > kEps) || (res < 0); ++i, k+=2)
        {
            numerator*=(-x*x/i);
            res+=numerator/k;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Here is what I am trying to compute:

[image]

When I try to pass 30 as an argument my computations go forever. What is wrong? I am very stuck, it seems for me like there is no error and everything should work just fine, but still it is not so.

Comment: Did you debug your code? Thought how it works by iterating in your mind? This code is very simple and the problem is obviously in your for loop conditions. Nothing special.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy, yes, I tried to debug it. Did not help me.

Comment: Nothing C about your code. Don't spam tags.

Comment: @StoryTeller, ok.

Comment: @user2672165, I tried long as well and that did not help.

Comment: It is not about C++ either, but about a numerical algorithm. SO is simply the wrong site for that.

Comment: "I tried to debug it. Did not help me." That's meaningless. What did you try? The very minimum would be printing the value of numerator at every step, which makes the issue obvious.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, do you mean that the problem is in the int overflow?

Comment: I just tested it with argument 30.0, and it returned 9.06067e+010

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, yep. There is a type overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although formally Taylor series converges, in practice you will run into machine precision limits even for the argument as small as 0.1 (and that is using kEps=0)

It's better to use (scaled appropriately) [std::erf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/erf) (C++11), or if it's a homework, look up an algorithm for computing erf function, e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97/how-to-accurately-calculate-the-error-function-erfx-with-a-computer

Comment: It says that namespace std has no member erf.